# JavaScript Two-Dimensional array is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was trying to resolve my error with other answers but just fail. I have this simple example of what I think is two-dimensional array but it keeps returning me undefined error.

```
var city = 'London',
    country = 'England';

var locate = [];
locate['London']['England'] = ['Jhon','Mike'];

for (i = 0; i < locate[city][country].length; i++) {  
  console.log(locate[city][country][i]);
}
```

jsbin http://jsbin.com/pixeluhojawa/1/

what am I doing wrong in this example, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: `locate['London']` is clearly undefined.

Comment: A 2x2 matrix / array in javascript is an Array inside an Array. Can you provide in matrix form what you are trying to put into the arrays? Are you try {[London, England], [John, Mike]}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you can assign a value to `locate['London']['England']`, you'll have to make sure that `locate['London']` is an object:

```
var locate = {};
locate['London'] = {};
locate['London']['England'] = ['Jhon','Mike'];
```

Notice how I used an object literal (`{}`) instead of an array literal (`[]`). Arrays don't support string keys like this. You'll need to use objects instead.

You can also declare it like this::

```
var locate = {
    London:{
        England:["Jhon","Mike"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Also it should be `locate = {}`. This isn't an array ;)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: I missed the obvious, edited the answer :P

Comment: I like more your other way of declaration but it says its missing semicolon. Is this correct structure var locate = {
    London:{
        England:["Jhon","Mike"]
    }
}

Comment: I'm glad to be of help, @devjs11 :-). `locate = {London:{England:"Jhon","Mike"]}} ` should work just fine.